# PostgreSQL: CAST() as money: specify currency

Tags: sql, postgresql, formatting

I'm looking to specify the currency as GBP when casting as money in PSQL. Currently, this prefixes the formatted value as USD (with $):

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(cost) AS MONEY) AS Total FROM orders;
```

Gives:

```
Total | $13,266,314.00
```

Is there a nice way way to specify `£` when casting to money instead of `$` or will this require `CONCAT()`, `ROUND()` and `TO_CHAR()`?

Comment: [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money) and this "single currency problem" is just one reason for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may set lc_monetary in postgresql.conf, or within your sql client. 
Here is the latter test case:

```
set lc_monetary to "en_IE.utf8";
select 10::money;

 money  
--------
 €10.00
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your currency locale to be pounds instead of dollars. You can do this by setting a value for [lc_monetary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-MONETARY).

```sql
SET lc_monetary = 'en_GB';
SELECT CAST(SUM(cost) AS MONEY) AS Total FROM orders;
```

As mentioned in the [locale docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/locale.html) you can get a list of available locales on a Unix system by running `locale -a`.